# Constrained Linear Optimization problem in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Objective - using given max values and coefficients, solve the linear equation within the constraints

Problem - defining the constraint

Code:

```
 import numpy as np
    coefficients = np.array([
          [0, 9, 6, 9, 4, 0 ],
          [0, 9, 7, 7, 3, 2 ],
          [0, 9, 5, 9, 3, 2 ],
          [0, 11, 2, 6, 4, 5],
          [0, 11, 1, 7, 2, 7],
          [1, 10, 1, 5, 3, 8]
    ])

    maxPoints = np.array([
        [4239100],
        [4204767],
        [4170434],
        [4136101],
        [4101768],
        [4067435]
    ])
    x = np.linalg.solve(coefficients, maxPoints)
    print(x)
```

Output

```
[[256694.51339286]
 [213778.26339286]
 [140820.63839286]
 [123654.13839286]
 [89321.13839286]
 [80737.88839286]]
```

The issue is that i want to apply a constraint making it so that:

```
x[0] <= x[1] <= x[2] <= x[3] <= x[4] <= x[5]
```

Another issue is that this currently only solves this smaller matrix and I need this to work with a much larger matrix were my maxPoints are 1 column by 32 rows and my coefficients are 6 columns by 32 rows. Using the linalg method above it would not solve this.

Heres the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled-1.py", line 74, in <module>
X = np.linalg.solve(coefficients, maxPoints)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in    solve
File "/home/comfortablynumb/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 390, in solve
_assertNdSquareness(a)
File "/home/comfortablynumb/.local/lib/python3.7/site- packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 213, in  _assertNdSquareness
raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

Here is the full data set I'm working with

```
`maxPoints = np.array([
        [4239100],
        [4204767],
        [4170434],
        [4136101],
        [4101768],
        [4067435],
        [4033102],
        [3998769],
        [3964436],
        [3930103],
        [3895770],
        [3861437],
        [3827104],
        [3792771],
        [3758438],
        [3724105],
        [3689772],
        [3655439],
        [3621106],
        [3586773],
        [3552440],
        [3518107],
        [3483774],
        [3449441],
        [3415108],
        [3380775],
        [3346442],
        [3312109],
        [3277776],
        [3243443],
        [3209110],
        [3174777]])`

    `coefficients = np.array([ 
        [0, 9, 6, 9, 4, 0 ],
        [0, 9, 7, 7, 3, 2 ],
        [0, 9, 5, 9, 3, 2 ],
        [0, 11, 2, 6, 4, 5],
        [0, 11, 1, 7, 2, 7],
        [1, 10, 1, 5, 3, 8],  
        [2, 9, 1, 5, 2, 9 ],
        [2, 8, 2, 4, 3, 9 ],
        [2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 9 ],
        [2, 8, 1, 4, 1, 12],
        [3, 6, 1, 5, 1, 12],
        [4, 5, 1, 5, 0, 13],
        [5, 4, 1, 5, 0, 13],
        [5, 4, 0, 5, 1, 13],
        [5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 13],
        [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 13],
        [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 13],
        [6, 3, 2, 3, 1, 13],
        [6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 14],
        [6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 14],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 14],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16]
     ])`
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXHvC_FGx24 ?

Comment: taking a look trying to figure out to set bounds and initial guess then id need to iterate through each equation so that it solves all of them

Comment: I suggest to write down the problem in proper mathematical notation. I suspect it is a linear least squares problem with some side constraints. But I am not sure from this description.  In general, least squares problems with side constraints can be solved as a QP (Quadratic Programming) problem. QP solvers for Python are readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Constraints**

Presuming that you are referring to a linear system of equations of the form:

ax = b

where a is a matrix of values (`coefficients`) in your code snippet, and b is a vector of constants (`maxPoints`) in your code, then you are solving for x.

Adding constraints doesn't really make sense here, as the system is soluble if:

1. `coefficients` is invertible (or at least, has a pseudoinverse).
2. All elements of `maxPoints` are finite.

**The LinAlgError**

In essence, you can think of `numpy.linalg.solve(a,b)` doing the following:

Solve: `ax = b` for x

One can think of this in a sense as `numpy` computing the inverse of the matrix a. Here, `numpy` raised a `LinAlgError` because the matrix was not square, and therefore the inverse is poorly defined. `numpy` actually does some other little bits behind the scenes (see LAPACK), but this is close enough for discussion here.

**What I think may be the issue**

You have the following problem:

- The number of columns in `coefficients` is 6, and the number of rows is 32.
- The number of rows in `maxPoints` is 32.
- This is an over-determined problem.

A first step would be to use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)). You can use exactly the same syntax.

`x_ls = np.linalg.lstsq(coefficients, maxPoints)`

This solver yields an answer which minimizes the squared Euclidean 2-norm. *Instead* you want to minimize using the constraint that `x[j] <= x[j+1]` for all `j < len(x)`.

**Some steps towards a solution**

I may come back and edit this later with a Github snippet, as it's quite an interesting problem.

*Edit:* `trust-constr` seemed to work much better for this than SLSQP.

I think you should have a bit of a further read of the [optimization documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#sequential-least-squares-programming-slsqp-algorithm-method-slsqp) in `scipy`, particularly the `trust-constr` algorithm. I think you pretty much want to do a least squares solution on part of your matrix, then iterate forward. As a plausible algorithm:

1. Solve using `trust-constr` on the problem with 2 columns only (corresponding to x[4] and x[5]). Bounds (choose `BOUND` freely):

   - x[4]: `[-np.inf,BOUND]`
   - x[5]: `[BOUND, np.inf]`
2. Solve again with 3 columns (x[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Px6.png), x[4], x[5]). Bounds (with _p denoting value obtained from previous step):

   - x[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Px6.png): `[-np.inf,x_p[4]]`
   - x[4]: `[x_p[4],x_p[5]]`
   - x[5]: `[x_p[5],np.inf]`
3. Repeat similarly until you solve for the full 6 columns.

It's not the best algorithm in the world, however, your constraint will be satisfied, and the iterative nature will correct a little bit if you do pick a bad value of `BOUND` to start with. If you wish to obtain a global solution, you can repeat for many different values of bound, and see which one returns the lowest error in the final `trust-constr` fit.

*Edit:* for an implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

# Set up bounds and make a,b objects
a,b = coefficients, maxPoints[:,0]

# Set acceptable bounds to be whatever you like here.
# I've chosen -100000 to 100000 in steps of 10000.
iter_of_acceptable_bounds = range(-100000,100000,10000)

def e2n(x,*args):
    'Compute the sum of the residuals (Euclidean 2-norm).'
    a,b = args
    return np.inner(b-a@x,b-a@x)

solutions, errors = [], []
for BOUND in iter_of_acceptable_bounds:   
    # Repeat the algorithm for each initial choice of bounds.

    # Generate an array for the bounds, based no the initial choice.
    bounds_arr = np.concatenate(([-np.inf],[BOUND,BOUND],[np.inf]))

    for i in range(2,a.shape[1]+1):
        # Initial guess of 0.
        x0 = [0 for j in range(i)]

        # Start with 2 columns, end at a.shape[1]
        # (a.shape[1]==6 for the example).

        bounds = Bounds(
                *bounds_arr.reshape(i,2).T.tolist()
                )

        # Slice up a accordingly
        A = a[:,-i:]

        # Minimize using trust-constr, and unpack the solution
        xr = minimize(e2n,x0,
                 args=(A,b),
                 bounds=bounds,
                 method='trust-constr').x

        # Generate a new array for the bounds, dynamically based on the previous choices.
        bounds_arr = np.concatenate(
                        [[-np.inf]] + [(xr[j],xr[j]) for j in range(i)] + [[np.inf]]
                        )

    # Save the solution and error from the full matrix
    solutions.append(xr)
    errors.append(np.sqrt(e2n(xr,a,b)))
```

This seems to perform fairly well. If we make a quick plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# lstsq, for comparison (no constraints)
lstsq_fit, lstsq_res, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(a,b)
lstsq_err = np.sqrt(lstsq_res)

# Plot errors
plt.plot(iter_of_acceptable_bounds,100*(errors-lstsq_err)/lstsq_err)
plt.xlabel('Starting choice of BOUND for algorithm')
plt.ylabel('Increase in error compared to numpy.linalg.lstsq')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In general, `numpy.linalg.lstsq` will solve this problem fairly well (it is just a linear regression problem), however it doesn't have the desired constraint. However, generally speaking this algorithm is okay -- the data fits only around 40% worse than `numpy.linalg.lstsq` for some of our choices of `BOUND`.

From this coarse search, the best values were given by:

```
>>> my_sol = solutions[errors.index(min(errors))]
>>> print(my_sol) 
array([-186017.00778511,    6680.13364168,  184099.89046232,
        220587.55247874,  257275.09670101,  257275.09670101])
```

Comment: I added the full data set in the original post, this is my first time ever working with anything like this, so I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1: Formulate a mathematical model

The description is wordy and not very precise. Hence I am not sure if this is the correct mathematical model, but this is my interpretation:

[image]

`r` can be interpreted as residuals. I think the reference to **max values** in the question implies that `b>=Ax` or as I stated: `r>=0`. Of course, it is easy to drop the `r>=0` restriction.

This is a least squares problem with some side constraints. It is formulated as a quadratic programming (QP) problem.

Note that it is also possible to formulate this with a linear objective: just minimize the sum of the r's. That would give you an LP problem.

### Step 2: Implementation, i.e. write some code

With the mathematical model under the belt, it is very easy to write some code:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import pandas as pd

b = np.array([[4239100],[4204767],[4170434],[4136101],[4101768],[4067435],[4033102],[3998769],[3964436],[3930103],
        [3895770],[3861437],[3827104],[3792771],[3758438],[3724105],[3689772],[3655439],[3621106],[3586773],[3552440],
        [3518107],[3483774],[3449441],[3415108],[3380775],[3346442],[3312109],[3277776],[3243443],[3209110],[3174777]])

A = np.array([[0, 9, 6, 9, 4, 0 ],[0, 9, 7, 7, 3, 2 ],[0, 9, 5, 9, 3, 2 ],[0, 11, 2, 6, 4, 5],[0, 11, 1, 7, 2, 7],
        [1, 10, 1, 5, 3, 8],[2, 9, 1, 5, 2, 9 ],[2, 8, 2, 4, 3, 9 ],[2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 9 ],[2, 8, 1, 4, 1, 12],
        [3, 6, 1, 5, 1, 12],[4, 5, 1, 5, 0, 13],[5, 4, 1, 5, 0, 13],[5, 4, 0, 5, 1, 13],[5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 13],
        [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 13],[5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 13],[6, 3, 2, 3, 1, 13],[6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 14],[6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 14],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 14],[6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],[6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 16],[6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],[6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],[6, 4, 1, 1, 0, 16],[7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],[7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],[7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],
        [7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16],[7, 3, 1, 1, 0, 16]])

m,n = np.shape(A)
print("m,n=",m,n)
x = cp.Variable((n,1))
r = cp.Variable((m,1),nonneg=True)
ordered = [x[i] >= x[i-1] for i in range(1,n)]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(r)),
                  [r == b-A@x] + ordered)
prob.solve(verbose=True)
print("x:\n",pd.DataFrame(x.value))
print("r:\n",pd.DataFrame(r.value))
```

The CVXPY model is solved by the default QP solver: OSQP. This is a fairly new, open source, first-order algorithm. The solver log looks like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           OSQP v0.6.0  -  Operator Splitting QP Solver
              (c) Bartolomeo Stellato,  Goran Banjac
        University of Oxford  -  Stanford University 2019
-----------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n = 38, constraints m = 69
          nnz(P) + nnz(A) = 278
settings: linear system solver = qdldl,
          eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,
          eps_prim_inf = 1.0e-04, eps_dual_inf = 1.0e-04,
          rho = 1.00e-01 (adaptive),
          sigma = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.60, max_iter = 10000
          check_termination: on (interval 25),
          scaling: on, scaled_termination: off
          warm start: on, polish: on, time_limit: off

iter   objective    pri res    dua res    rho        time
   1   0.0000e+00   4.24e+06   1.18e+10   1.00e-01   5.06e-04s
 200   5.6400e+11   3.43e+01   9.03e+00   1.03e+00   1.68e-03s
 225   5.6410e+11   1.06e+01   2.79e+00   1.03e+00   2.50e-03s
plsh   5.6415e+11   2.79e-09   1.77e-08   --------   3.22e-03s

status:               solved
solution polish:      successful
number of iterations: 225
optimal objective:    564145476298.7255
run time:             3.22e-03s
optimal rho estimate: 1.44e+00
```

The solution vector `x` looks like:

```
x:
                0
0 -101723.089140
1   60977.386991
2  174769.759793
3  189344.863121
4  208736.990006
5  208736.990006
```

Of course in practice we would scale things a bit (change of units). The numbers for `b`, `x` and the objective are a bit large.